# MS Excel - Paste a formula from a tab-delimited line

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Visual Studio program that reads a PDF file and scrapes data from it. The VS program then generates a tab-delimited string that is manually pasted into the spreadsheet.
Everything works fine, but my tab-delimited line erases a formula in one column.  Not a big deal as I just copy the formula from the previous line.

Would it be possible to put the formula into my tab-delimited line?

Here is the formula:

```
=IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK($M2666)),ISBLANK($O2666)),"y","")
```

If I put this into the tab-delimited line in the appropriate column, it works fine, if I happen to be inserting the tab-delimited line on row 2666.

I tried using the `row()` function, but then it's not a valid formula:

```
=IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK($Mrow())),ISBLANK($Orow())),"y","")
```

I tried a function that returns the last row in a given column then made a variable to put into the formula. If I am just pasting in Excel, it works, but when I try to insert it in a tab-delimited line is pastes as text.

Remember, the tab-delimited string is being generated in a program external to the spreadsheet and the program doesn't have access to the spreadsheet to find the last used row.

So, here's the question, how do I paste a formula from the clipboard?

Comment: `...,ISBLANK($Orow())),"y","")...` is `$Orow()` a typo? I think what you're wanting to do is `ISBLANK($O & row())` not `ISBLANK($Orow())` which Excel won't like.

Comment: Do you know what row you're inserting to when creating the string to add?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INDIRECT` and `ADDRESS`... and also `ROW` and `COLUMN`:
Please search every detail on that function if you need to know.

Say you want get value of `M2666` from `Q2666` with the formula `INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW();COLUMN()-4))`. Back to the example problem, with assumption the formula is inserted in `Q2666`, then your formula should be:

```
=IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW();COLUMN()-4))));ISBLANK(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW();COLUMN()-2))));"y";"")
```

Please notice that Excel uses `;` not `,` to separate parameters in a function.

Answer (score 0):

This question is tagged as [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) so here is my VBA-based solution.

```
dim strFormula as string

strFormula = "=IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(RC13)),ISBLANK(RC15)),""y"","""")"
range("M2").formular1c1 = strFormula
range("M2666").formular1c1 = strFormula
range("M9999").formular1c1 = strFormula
```

The [Range.FormulaR1C1 property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb213527(v=office.12).aspx) accepts the **xlR1C1** style formula that will adjust for any row you place it into.

If you place the xlR1C1 style formula into a tab delimited TXT file, the following code would be necessary before and after using VBA to import the TXT file.

```
dim origRefStyle as long

origRefStyle = Application.ReferenceStyle
Application.ReferenceStyle = xlR1C1

'import the tab delimited TXT here

Application.ReferenceStyle = origRefStyle
```

Comment: Thank you for the replies - I will try the suggestions later today.
Bruce - no, not a typo, just a senior moment.
Tim - That's the problem, I *don't* know the row at the time of insertion.  The VB studio program generates the line and places it into the clipboard, and it is manually pasted into the spreadsheet.  I should be able to insert it directly into the spreadsheet, but that is above my pay scale and would stretch my brain too much.

Again, the responses are very much appreciated.